# Best design for product list page of an e-commerce website

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, accessibility, e-commerce

I am working on an e-commerce website. I want to display the summary of search result and want to know which layout is the best?

The information that I am sowing are:

1. Ad title
2. Price
3. Location
4. Advertiser name

**Design 1:**
[image]

**Design 2:**
[image]

**Design 3:**
[image]

**Design 4:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Accessibility

Option 5 - none of the above.

For every one of them you are using light grey text which is not high enough contrast with the background. You need to darken the text.

Use a [colour contrast checker](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) to ensure your text colour is dark enough...then make it a little bit darker for good measure.

Anyway that doesn't answer your question, it is just a tongue in cheek way of pointing it out and you added the accessibility tag so I was bound to mention it!

### Which Layout

As for the layout of the text, it is subjective at this stage, what you want to do (if you have enough traffic) is pick the one you like the most and then use A / B testing to see which one results in the most engagement.

It also very much depends on the type of site. Is it another gumtree type site? Then maybe the location is important. With that being said, if you can set a maximum search radius and order by closest then it is less important (but at that point you would want to display "XX km / miles away" instead of the location).

If people can offer postage then there is very little issue with location so it should be lower priority.

As another example, are people on the site likely to make decisions based on price more than anything else (price sensitive). If so then don't waste their time by making the price small and hard to see, make it large so they can skip past stuff that is too expensive for them. If they are not price sensitive (they will pay for quality) then the price is less important.

You can apply the same logic to the other two fields, is the advertiser something that people need to know (will people seek out a certain person as they shop here regularly) or does it not matter (most visitors are one off visitors or visit infrequently). Same with the Ad Title - do people actually read it or are the pictures enough (this last one is a bit silly, almost certainly the title is high priority)

My personal preference is the first design, the hierarchy of:

- What is it
- Where is it
- How much is it
- Who is advertising (remove it, I don't see the value in showing this on the listings?)

Feels the most logical in terms of information I might want to know, but that is judged purely on the pictures and product descriptions provided.

As I said - pick one based on what information you believe is most important and then A / B test it. If you don't have enough traffic to A / B test then just pick one that fits the usage of the site.